# Simulation of LTE networks using Mininet

Tags: networking, openflow

I am planning to do a project on WIFI offloading using Software Defined Networking. Basically to switch the signals from WIFI to LTE and vice-versa based on the signal strength. Could anybody let me know how i could simulate this and carry out certain experimental tests? I know there is a software called Mininet and i am not sure if we can create base-stations to simulate the experiments. Is it possible to simulate this using Mininet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can sett up some link parameters such as bandwidth and latency in mininiet to "emulate" an wireless base station (LTE/WIFI). However, I'm not quite sure how you should emulate signal strength. You could of course write a program with a "node" that moves around on a 3 axis graph where the x,y,z values could give some signal strength value based on output effect multiplied with the vector found in the graph, and when it reaches a threshold have it change to a node (mininet link) that is closer. I.e. change the forwarding tables so your "stream"/tunnel uses another link.

Answer (score 1):

I did an undergraduate thesis on wireless network emulation in Mininet and used Mininet and Ns-3 together using [this project](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Link-modeling-using-ns-3). We primarily did validity testing on this platform to determine it's accuracy and limitations (especially at scale). The wireless model is very good until a very clear performance degradation when the CPU usage reaches (100/n)% - where n is the number of available cores on the machine (for a single threaded implementation).

It also has the functionality to set up multiple base stations, although I didn't delve deeply into this beyond initial testing that it works. The main benefits achieved through this tool is the accurate performance degradation due to distance from the source and interference.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of time has past and it seems better ways are available:

- [ns-3](https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/LAA-WiFi-Coexistence) has [LTE features](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.17/models/html/lte.html) (it seems it got it through [LENA](http://networks.cttc.es/mobile-networks/software-tools/lena/))
- for mininet-wifi, [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Which_emulator_for_the_emulation_of_SDN_based_Wifi_LTE_small_cells), [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-26470-7_5) and [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8484764)